# How to download webDAV files from a linux server

Tags: webdav, splunk, sfdc

I have several log files in a webDAV (salesforce SFDC logs repo) and I want to drop all of them to a linux server, so that I can feed them to splunk. I am not sure if there is a better idea than this, please advise.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How do drop all of my logs to a Linux server to feed them to Splunk

Comment: Any insights on this please ?

Comment: Someone please advise